# How do I make AngularJS update input values?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to figure out why my last input won't update.

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzcvukq8/)

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzcvukq8/

I think there's something wrong with my JS

```js
function calculatorController($scope){
 // Sixteen oz
 $scope.costPerCanSixteen = function(){
  return $scope.priceSixteen/(24*$scope.casesSixteen);
 };
};
```

```css
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```html
    <div id="sixteen-oz" ng-controller="calculatorController">
      <div class='hr'></div>
      <h1>One</h1>
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputCases" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Amount of Cases</label>
          <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
            <input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="2500" class="form-control" ng-model="casesSixteen"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputCost" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Cost Per Case</label>
          <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
            <input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="2500" class="form-control" placeholder="29.40" ng-model="priceSixteen"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="canCost" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Cost Per Can</label>
          <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control answer-to-input" value="{{ costPerCanSixteen() }}"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: the problem isn't in the code you posted in the question body at all.  The problem is in the way that you declared the input in your HTML.  You can't put an expression in the `value` tag, and it's not really good practice to call a function from an expression like this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="calculatorController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="priceSixteen"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="casesSixteen"/>
    <button ng-click="costPerCanSixteen()">click</button>
    <p>{{costPerCanSixteen}}</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**app.js**

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("calculatorController", function($scope) {    

        $scope.costPerCanSixteen = function(){
            var priceSixteen = $scope.priceSixteen;
           var casesSixteen = $scope.casesSixteen;

            $scope.costPerCanSixteen = priceSixteen/(24*casesSixteen);
        };
    });
```

another way..
**script.js**

```
function calculatorController($scope){

    $scope.costPerCanSixteen = function(){
      var costPerCanSixteen = 0;
      var priceSixteen = $scope.priceSixteen;
      var casesSixteen = $scope.casesSixteen;

      costPerCanSixteen = priceSixteen/(24*casesSixteen);

      return costPerCanSixteen;
    };
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>

    <body ng-app ng-controller="calculatorController">

        <form>
            <div class="total">
                <!-- Calculate the total price of all chosen services. Format it as currency. -->
                <input type="text" ng-model="priceSixteen"/>
                <input type="text" ng-model="casesSixteen"/>
                Total: <span>{{costPerCanSixteen() | currency}}</span>
            </div>

        </form>

        <!-- Include AngularJS from Google's CDN -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```